# JHipster/OpenAPI: How do you do entity persistence?

Tags: persistence, jhipster, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate a project via JHipster with the OpenAPI option specified.

1. Create an OpenAPI specification file to define the entities and paths defining the application.
2. Create a JHipster .jdl file to specify the JHipster project parameters.

   - There are **no** entity definitions - this is intended to be provided by the OpenAPI file.
3. Execute JHipster (`> jhipster import-jdl <file>.jdl`).
4. Copy my OpenAPI file into `src/main/resources/swagger/api.yml`.
5. Execute OpenAPI sub-generator (`> mvnw generate-sources`).

This generates a microservice project, including the relevant OpenAPI classes generated by the OpenAPI sub-generator.

One very noticeable thing is missing: *There is no code that deals with object persistence.*

*What do I need to do to provide this capability?*

I know that JHipster has an entity sub-generator (entities can be defined in the JDL as well). This will generate a slew of code related to the defined entities, including persistence logic. However, this doesn't seem to fit well with the idea of defining entities in the OpenAPI specification file. I can't conceive of how these two techniques could possibly work together.

Has anyone done this?

---

Here are the relevant files for the curious:

[This is obviously an extremely simplistic application and persisting anything really makes little sense, but I'm providing it for illustration.]

jhipster.jdl:

```
application {
  config {
    packageName com.example
    baseName echoMicroservice

    applicationType microservice
    serverPort 9100

    buildTool maven
    authenticationType jwt
    clientPackageManager npm

    serviceDiscoveryType no
    messageBroker false
    searchEngine false

    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType mysql
    prodDatabaseType mysql

    cacheProvider hazelcast
    enableHibernateCache false

    clientFramework angularX
    enableSwaggerCodegen true
  }
}
```

echo-api.yml:

```
openapi: '3.0.1'
info:
  title: 'echoMicroservice'
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:9100
    description: Development server
  - url: https://localhost:9100
    description: Development server with TLS Profile
paths:
  /random:
    get:
      summary: Returns a random message
      description: Returns a random message
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Random response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
  /echo:
    post:
      summary: Echoes a specified message
      description: Echoes a specified message
      requestBody:
        description: Echo request
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Echo response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Echo'
components:
  schemas:
    Echo:
      type: object
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
```

Comment: Your API model does not need to be your persistence model. Define your entities using JDL and map them to your  API DTOs in your service layer. API first will not generate frontend part as well, if you want to get the most of JHipster, generate entities from JDL with DTOs and adapt DTOs and UI to your need.

Comment: Hmm, so I should define the entities in the JDL and not in the API definition? How do I go about the "mapping"? Does this need to be done manually, or can that be automated?

Comment: Does this mean I will have entity definitions in the JDL, create the entities so that they have corresponding DTOs (not that I'm sure what these are or how they are to be used) and my OpenAPI definitions and somehow the DTO "maps" between the JDT objects and the OpenAPI objects? I'm very confused.

Comment: If you're confused, try on a test project. If you're still confused , forget about API first.

Comment: Sorry if it sounded harsh, it was not my intention. I just meant to say that I doubt this option does what you want .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202361/discussion-between-joseph-gagnon-and-gael-marziou).